# Отсекание части текста. С#

Tags: c#, строки

По заданию, мне нужно ввести в консоль приложение, после чего найти количество слов в тексте, самое длинное слово в тексте, вывести его длину и самое главное - **если текст превышает 140 символов, то отсечь все, что превышает и вернуть остаточный текст**

Если с первыми заданиями я еще справился, используя гугл + msdn, то с возвратом текста на 140 символов - серьезные проблемы.

Не могу понять, что вкладывать в переменную, чтобы substring сработал. Код ниже. В программировании я новичок, попрошу попроще мне объяснять, пожалуйста

```
Console.Write("Введите строку: ");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] str = input.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '!', '?', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        int maxlen = 0, index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (str[i].Length > maxlen)
            {
                maxlen = str[i].Length;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Самое длинное слово: {0}", str[index]);
        Console.WriteLine("Длинна самого длинного слова {0}", str[index].Length);
        int CountWords = input.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '!', '?', ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        Console.WriteLine("Количество слов в тексте {0}", CountWords);

        var textCount = 140;
        if(str[index].Length > textCount)
        {
            var shortText = str[index].Substring(140, 200);
            Console.WriteLine(shortText)
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `input = input.Substring(0, 140);` ?

Comment: А зачем вы делаете еще раз Split для подсчета количества слов? У вас ведь уже есть массив слов, возьмите  int wordsCount = str.Length; Как отсечь подстроку подсказали выше